# Get Angular Child routes from API

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I want to get child routes from a database table. Can anyone please tell me how to call an api endpoint and bind the response to build child routes for a particular module.

I don't want to build the entire routes for the application but only for a particular parent route.

```
RouterModule.forChild(childRoutes)
```

So here I want to get childRoutes from API instead of hardcoding in the application.

Thanks,
Sathish

Comment: Child routes should be already defined in routing module in a lot of application unless you application is very dynamic that you can't even predict what routes will you have
So if your routes are somehow known and static, then I think you are over engineering the matter

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Mina,  but yes our application needs to be dynamic as the admin wants to create more menu items and assign roles to these items. Even want to control the sort order and set active or inactive from the Admin module.